# VirtualBox image from running VPS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, migration

I have an Ubuntu Server 10.04 VPS (Virtual Private Server) that hosts my website. I would like to clone this VPS and create a VirtualBox machine from it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to look at the command `VBoxManage convertfromraw` or `VBoxManage clonehd`.  I can't remember exactly how to do it, but I found these two guides: http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Migrate_Windows and http://www.pendrivelinux.com/boot-a-usb-flash-drive-in-virtualbox/.

Once you have the hard drive converted, you can just create a new Virtual Machine, but use your existing disk image you just created.

Comment: I realize that the first document is about migrating Windows, but near the end, they show a command to convert a device file on Linux to a VDI.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to migrate the whole installation byte-for-byte, in essence making a copy of the disk: read [penguin359's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11706/virtualbox-image-from-running-vps/11729#11729), or see [Moving linux install to a new computer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2865/moving-linux-install-to-a-new-computer/2868#2868).

If you just want to reproduce the settings of an existing installation: install a basic system from scratch, then run `aptitude-create-state-bundle` on the VPS to export your package selection and APT settings, and run `aptitude-run-state-bundle` to import these settings into the VirtualBox installation (and in particular get the same set of packages installed). Then migrate your customizations: `/etc` (where you'll have to change a few files), `/home`, and `/var/www` or wherever you keep your web server data. See also [How do I migrate configuration between computers with different hardware?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7364/how-do-i-migrate-configuration-between-computers-with-different-hardware/7401#7401). See also [a step-by-step cloning guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/386/how-can-i-most-easily-migrate-all-my-apps-and-settings-from-one-ubuntu-install-to/5025#5025), which addresses what files you'll most likely need to change in `/etc`.