# List explicitly removed packages (apt)

Tags: apt, package-management, deb, trisquel

The [question unix.SE/3595](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3595/18768) asks how to list packages that I explicitly installed. By explicit it means, packages that I choose, not including anything installed by default, or pulled in by the dependencies.

Is there a similar command to find packages that were ***explicitly removed***?

Answer (score 5):

The following command will list all packages which have ever been removed (or purged), as far back as `apt`'s history allows:

```
zgrep -E '^(Remove:|Purge)' /var/log/apt/history.log*
```

This does *not* distinguish automatic removals from explicit removals, but with a little work you should be able to reconstruct that information.

If you always use the command line, then

```
zgrep -E ^Commandline /var/log/apt/history.log*
```

will show you all the commands you issued, which will include explicit removals. You could filter it to only list `remove` or `purge`, but that won't include other forms of removals.

If you remove packages using `dpkg`, that won't appear in `apt`'s logs; you'd need to look at `/var/log/dpkg.log` and search for `remove` or `purge`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a way to do this using apt, but you may try searching your bash history:

```
grep 'apt-get .*remove' ~/.bash_history
```

This should output all lines with remove or autoremove.

Comment: That's what I do, it's a good poor man's listing. But not every terminal session is saved to bash history. See eg. [unix.SE/1288: Preserve bash history in multiple terminal windows](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/); maybe including connection loss, screen/terminal multiplexer, who knows what, some of which already effects me.

Comment: You may want to check this topic: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425809/where-are-the-logs-for-apt-get

Basically you can try searching various logs of apt and see if there is anything you can fit into some pattern.

Answer (score 0):

There should be logs located at `/var/log/apt/history.log` that contain your past actions with apt.